# Attacking chessboard squares with 6 pieces

Tags: chess, checkerboard

Place 6 white pieces (a king, a queen, a rook, a bishop, a knight and a pawn) on 6 different squares of a regular 8x8 chessboard so that there is at least one empty square attacked by exactly one piece, at least one empty square attacked by exactly two pieces, ..., at least one empty square attacked by exactly six pieces.

---

This puzzle is generalized [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125896/general-attacking-chessboard-squares).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This configuration seems to work:

> [image]

> Only the Knight attacks F1
>
>  Queen and Bishop attack G8
>
>  Queen, Bishop and Knight attack G4
>
>  King, Rook, Bishop and Knight attack C4
>
>  Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop and Pawn attack F5
>
>  All pieces attack D5

Comment: What about the ellipsis? Which squares are attacked by exactly 3/4/5 pieces?

Comment: I had the same solution except I had the queen on b3.